# Concatenating MySQL Query into single row for each user

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have a query as such in which I am trying to get values for each user within another table into one outputted row in the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.ID, table1.username, table1.display_name,
                 CASE WHEN table2.meta_key = 'vgm' THEN table2.meta_value END VGM,
                 CASE WHEN table2.meta_key = 'year_completed' THEN table2.meta_value END 'Year Completed',
                 CASE WHEN table2.meta_key = 'status' THEN table2.meta_value END Status,
                 CASE WHEN table2.meta_key = 'military_grade' THEN table2.meta_value END 'Military Grade'
          FROM   table1, table2
          WHERE  table1.ID = table2.user_id
```

What I end up with is results like below. I'd like all user info in a single row if possible. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>Baja</td>
<td>NULL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>112</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>Subt</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
<td>NULL</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table 1 is as such:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>NAME</td>
<td>EMAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>user1</td>
<td>Username Last</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>user2</td>
<td>Username2 Last2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table 2 is as such:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>USER_ID</td>
<td>META_KEY</td>
<td>META_VALUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>Key 1</td>
<td>Value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>Key 2</td>
<td>Value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>Key 1</td>
<td>Value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>Key 2</td>
<td>Value 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Isn't your result already in a single row?

Comment: If you run the code snippit the output has 4 different rows for one user. It should only be one row with no NULL values. The other table has multiple values each on their own row and I'm trying to condense all user info into one table row.

Comment: I see, can you please post your table schema for table1 and table2 and some sample data.  I am thinking this can be solved by using joins instead of a from with two tables.  I would need the see the requested info first tho before providing a new query.

Comment: Updated with both table schema as requested.

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer given your new info.  Please let me know if it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the query below and yours is I take `table2` and create a subquery for each `meta_key` and then join those subqueries to `table1` using a `LEFT JOIN`.  This should then result in a single record for each user.

Your table schema and query have some inconsistencies, such as, `table1` has `user_name` and `display_name` but the schema has `NAME` and `EMAIL`.  I went ahead and used your query's field names.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT
    users.ID AS Id,
    users.username AS UserName,
    users.display_name AS DisplayName,
    vgm.meta_value AS VGM,
    year_completed.meta_value AS YearCompleted,
    status.meta_value AS Status,
    military_grade.meta_value AS MilitaryGrade

-- Users --
FROM table1 AS users

-- VGM --
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE meta_key = 'vgm') 
AS vgm ON users.ID = vgm.user_id

-- Year Completed --
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE meta_key = 'year_completed') 
AS year_completed ON users.ID = year_completed.user_id

-- Status --
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE meta_key = 'status') 
AS status ON users.ID = status.user_id

-- Military Grade --
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE meta_key = 'military_grade') 
AS military_grade ON users.ID = status.user_id
```